# validating array params via function

Tags: php

Why does `myFunction()` below validate the given parameter as true? This was caught by mistake as `myFunction` should normally receive the entire array as a parameter, but in this case only a specific value (`"35"`) within the array was passed to the function.  Yet, it still validated as true.  What am I missing here as I would not expect the parameter to validate as true, it was passed a string, not an array?

```
$myVar = array('id' => '35');
myFunction($myVar['id']);

function myFunction($params) {
    if (isset($params['id']) && !empty($params['id']) && $params['id'] == intval($params['id']) && $params['id'] > 0) {
        echo "id is valid<br>";
        echo "id = " . $params['id'] . "<br>";
        echo "params = " . $params . "<br>";
        print_r($params);
    } else {
        echo "id is invalid";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
id is valid
id = 3
params = 35
35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [strict comparison](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.operators.comparison.php) here `$params['id'] == intval($params['id'])` and PHP juggles with the types. Change it to `$params['id'] === intval($params['id'])`.

Or use [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) function.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks for pointing that out.  On a related note, why does isset($params['id']) return true?  The function received a string, not an array containing 'id' as a key.

Comment: I missed that somehow :) When I run the code you posted I see ```id is invalid```. Could it be you didn't restart the web server (it seems you are checking the result in a browser) after you changed ```myFunction($myVar);``` to ```myFunction($myVar['id']);```.

Comment: That's interesting that you get a different result.  I've dumbed the test code down so that the function simply checks if $params['id'] isset and it still returns true.  I've tested via web server (i.e. browser) as well as CLI.  This box is running PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: Try adding ```echo json_encode($params) . "<br>\n";``` to the beginning of the function and see what you are passing as arguments.

Comment: returns "35" (in quotes)

Comment: It looks like PHP has changed some of the behavior or perhaps there was a bug in earlier code (would have to confirm that first though).  Trying the sample code in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ with different versions (5.3.10 vs 5.4.0) returns different results.  5.4.0 returns "invalid", as expected.

Comment: Wow, the mystery is solved. I tried running it on 5.3.0 and really see what you said. Interesting.